# Python date separating a multiple year date span to single year spans

Tags: python, date

I am not sure if this is the appropriate title but I could not find a better one.

Say I have a date span:

```
 12 Nov 2012 - 15 May 2014
```

Is there an easy way for separating this span to single year spans like:

```
12 Nov 2012 - 31 Dec 2012
01 Jan 2013 - 31 Dec 2013
01 Jan 2014 - 15 May 2014
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily turn a range expressed in `datetime.date` objects into a sequence of `(start, end)` objects within a year:

```
from datetime import date

def year_boundaries(start, end):
    while start.year != end.year:
        yield start, date(start.year, 12, 31)
        start = date(start.year + 1, 1, 1)
    yield (start, end)
```

Demo:

```
>>> for start, end in year_boundaries(date(2012, 11, 12), date(2014, 5, 15)):
...     print start, '-', end
... 
2012-11-12 - 2012-12-31
2013-01-01 - 2013-12-31
2014-01-01 - 2014-05-15
```